# JS Trying to give a select effect to a tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply a 'select like' effect with JS, my function is triggered
on onClick event
 and it change the tag style, but the tag style remains unchanged after selected a new tag,
 the main idea of the first block of code is reset to the default style the old selections, but doesn't work..

```
function selectEffect(tag){
  //Code to reset to the default style first if something is selected
  var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
  var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
  cssNode.type = 'text/css';
  cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
  cssNode.href = '../static/css/style.css';
  cssNode.media = 'screen';
  headID.appendChild(cssNode);

  //Code to apply a selected like style
  var element = document.getElementById(tag);
  element.style.backgroundColor='#7D9ABE';
  element.style.color='#ffffff';
  element.style.fontWeight='bold';
  }
```

What's wrong with it?, Any help is appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the advice of Stokedout, I did the trick:

```
var selectedTag;
function selectEffect(tag){

  if (selectedTag){
    var oldElement = document.getElementById(old_selectedRow);
    oldElement.style.backgroundColor=old_backgroundColor;
    oldElement.style.color=old_color;
    oldElement.style.fontWeight=old_fontWeight;
   }

  var element = document.getElementById(tag);
  element.style.backgroundColor='#7D9ABE';
  element.style.color='#ffffff';
  element.style.fontWeight='bold';
  }

function doit(tag){
   selectEffect(tag)
   selectedTag = tag;
   }


<a onclick="doit('id1');"></a>
```

seems lazy code but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the default style of the element first so you can reset it afterwards. To reset the original element you either keep track of it or you can simply default all elements.

Comment: No probs, if you're only invoking the function from the link's onclick event inline you could simplify the code by passing `this` instead of the `'id1'`